# How do I iterate up until a returned variable number in a javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, type-conversion

I would like to create a photo grid of NFTs a user has associated with their wallet address. I have created a method to return a URL to display in an image tag. I'm at the point now where I need to return multiple URLs to display all NFT images in a wallet. I have to iterate up until the balance of NFTs in the wallet using a for loop. I can return the balance of NFTs in the wallet using a async method and the convert that return string to a number. However, if I try and use the returned value in my for statement it doesn't work. If I use i<5 for example, it returns all the URLs. Also, if I say var num = 5 and then say i<num it also works. But if I use i<balance (where balance is my returned value) whether I convert it to a number using parseInt() or Number() it just skips over the for loop entirely. I know this because I console.log() something after the for loop and this shows up when using the variable instead of an actual number. As far as I can understand, this means the for loop is being skipped. Please check out my code below and let me know what the problem is.

```
async getNFTMetadata() {
  let balance = Number(await contract.methods.balanceOf(this.currentUser.walletAddress).call());
  console.log(balance);
  console.log(typeof(balance));
  var num =3;
  console.log(typeof(num));
  for (let i = 1; i <Number(balance); i++) {
    const result = await contract.methods.tokenURI(i).call()
    const request = new Request(result);
    const response = await fetch(request);
    const metadata = await response.json();
    const image = metadata.image;
    console.log(metadata);
    console.log(result);
    console.log(image);
  }
  console.log(balance)
}
```

Comment: `console.log(balance);
  console.log(typeof(balance));` what does this logs?

Comment: Those don't affect the code, I was just using them as means to troubleshoot and find where the problem source was. ```console.log(balance)``` is just a means to check whether the for loop was running and ```console.log(typeof(balance))``` was checking whether the type being returned by the balance variable was in fact a number, to see if that was the reason the for loop wasn't executing.

Comment: I was asking about the value of that

Comment: Thank you so much, when you made me think about what the problem was I realised that balance was a value of 1, and thats why it wasn't executing as the condition was  where i<1. It works now!